# Node Express 3.4.4 and Jade form data undefined

Tags: forms, node.js, post, express, pug

The following is by app.use section

```
// redis/session store
app.use(express.cookieParser());
app.use(express.session({ 
    store: new redisStore({ host: 'localhost', 
                            port: 6379, 
                            db: 2
                            }), 
    secret: SID
}));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

app.use(express.urlencoded());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
// all environments
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

app.use(express.favicon());
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(app.router);
app.use(require('stylus').middleware(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

and this is the routing

```
var saveProfile     = require('./routes/saveProfile');
.
.
.

// form handling 
app.post('/saveProfile',saveProfile.save);
```

and this is the handler for the form

```
exports.save = function(req,res) {
    try {
        var i = 0;
        console.log(req.body.displayName);
    }
    catch(e) {
        console.log(e.message);
    }
};
```

and finally the jade code which generates the actual form

```
form(method='POST',action='/saveProfile')
    div(class='topBannerHeading')
        span.
            Profile
        div
            input.formButton(type='submit',text='Save',value='Save')
    div(class='formHolder')
        h1.
            Your Cloud Services
        a(href='/googleRequestAuthorization')
            img.selectedService(src='images/Google-48x48.png',alt='Authorize Google')
        h1.
            Personal
        span
            div.
                Name:
            input#displayName(type='text',value=profile.displayName,style='width:300px')
            div.
                Address:
            input#AddressLine1(type='text',style='width:300px')
            div.

            input#AddressLine2(type='text',style='width:300px')
            div.
                Town:
            input#AddressTown(type='text',style='width:200px')
            div.
                County: 
            input#AddressCounty(type='text',style='width:200px')
            div.
                Post/Zip code   
            input#Postcode(type='text',style='width:200px')
            div(style='margin-top:40px').
                Telephone   
            input#Telephone(type='text',style='width:200px')
            div.
                Mobile: 
            input#Mobile(type='text',style='width:200px')
            div.
                Fax No: 
            input#FaxNo(type='text',style='width:200px')
            div.
                Email:  
            input#EmailAddress(type='text',style='width:300px',value=profile.email)
            div.
                Web:    
            input#WebAddress(type='text',style='width:300px')
            input#id(type='text',style='visibility:hidden')
```

Viewing the headers the request object

content-type is
    application/x-www-form-urlencoded

and the content length is coming back as 0 (zero)

I've tried adding `BodyParser()`

but still although it calls the handler `req.body.displayName` is undefined

any idea what I am doing wrong and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Name and not id. So where the jade file says

```
input#displayName(type='text',value=profile.displayName,style='width:300px')
```

and replace it with

```
input#displayName(type='text',name='displayName',value=profile.displayName,style='width:300px')
```

this was answered in another question that can be found here; [nodejs, express and jade: problems with inserts from form to database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20927190/nodejs-express-and-jade-problems-with-inserts-from-form-to-database?rq=1)